# How can I use a calculated value in a RegEx replace operation in C#?

Tags: c#, regex

I'm looking for a way to use the length of a match group in the replace expression with the  c# regex.replace function.

That is, what can I replace ??? with in the following example to get the desired output shown below?

**Example:**

```
val = Regex.Replace("xxx", @"(?<exes>x{1,6})", "${exes} - ???");
```

**Desired output**

```
X - 3
```

**Note:** This is an extremely contrived/simplified example to demonstrate the question. I realize for this example a regular expression is not the ideal way of doing this. Just trust me that the real world application of the answer is part of a more complex problem that does necessitate the use of a RegEx replace here.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try using the version of `Regex.Replace` that calls a function to determine what the replacement text should be:

```
public string Replace(string, MatchEvaluator);
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa332127(VS.71).aspx

The function could then look at the matched text (the `Match` object is supplied as the argument to the evaluator function) and return a string with the proper calculated value.

Comment: Thanks. I was thinking I needed to do that, but before I went down that road, I just wanted to see if there was a keyword recognized by replace to make this operation simpler.  Still, you've got my upvote and if no one responds with a shorthand way to accomplish this I'll accept this answer.

Answer (score 13):

If you are using C# 3 you can simply create a MatchEvaluator from a lambda expression:

```
string val = Regex.Replace(
   "xxx",
   @"(?<exes>x{1,6})",
   new MatchEvaluator(
      m => m.Groups["exes"].Value[0] + " - " + m.Groups["exes"].Value.Length.ToString()
   )
);
```

In C# 2 you can use a delegate:

```
string val = Regex.Replace(
   "xxx",
   @"(?<exes>x{1,6})",
   new MatchEvaluator(
      delegate(Match m) {
         return m.Groups["exes"].Value[0] + " - " + m.Groups["exes"].Value.Length.ToString();
      }
   )
);
```

Comment: In C# 4 at least creating a `new MatchEvaluator` is not necessary, the lambda-expression can be used directly.

Comment: string val = Regex.Replace(
   "xxx",
   @"(?<exes>x{1,6})",
   m => m.Groups["exes"].Value[0] + " - " + m.Groups["exes"].Value.Length.ToString()
);

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
val = Regex.Replace("xxx", @"(?<exes>x{1,6})", new MatchEvaluator(ComputeReplacement));
```

with the MatchEvaluator example below

```
public String ComputeReplacement(Match matchResult) {
  return matchResult.Value.Length.ToString();
}
```

(partially stolen from the Regular Expressions Cookbook -- my bible haha)