# Replacement of functions (to evaluate) in template variables

Tags: c#, regex, string

I have a piece of text something like

> Using only `{RAND(3,5)}` colors
>   paint a picture of a `{ITEM('duck','dog','cat')}`

What I'm trying to do is make a function that scans the string and picks out all text contained withing a set of braces and send them to a function, for example.

```
public string GenerateReplacementString(string input);
```

Where input would be RAND(3,5) or ITEM('duck','dog','cat') and the function would simply return a generated string from the input. Writing the function is the part I'm having no problem with, however I'm trying to discover what the most efficiant way is to scan the text for braces.

I thought at first using the `Regex.Replace` method in C#, however this only accepts a string (or char) replacement, and cannot accept a pointer to a generator function.

I suppose I could loop through and find all instances of { followed by } character by character but this seems exceedingly slow and expensive.

Is there some methodology I'm missing to allow dynamic search and replace of functions where you may not know the exact values of the string?

Comment: You believe there is a way to examine all characters in a string without looping through  them?

Comment: Sorry bad phrasing, without trying to build a stack of opening and closing { } and storing the opening and closing position of each ;)

Comment: As a follow-up to Eric's comment, RegEx will loop through the text (black box to you, but it still happens), and it will be less efficient than code optimized to solve this specific pattern matching problem.

Comment: This is not a duplicate of *that* question.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1256762/how-can-i-use-a-calculated-value-in-a-regex-replace-operation-in-c , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5585357/regex-dynamic-replacing , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5585357/regex-dynamic-replacing

Comment: And what will you do with `foo { BAR("}", "{") }` ? Hint: write a lexer.

Comment: The later part I'm not too worried about, I've wrote a parse tree for that since I know the syntax format for that.

Answer (score 1):

`Regex.Replace` *does* [have an overload that accepts a MatchEvaluator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ht1sxswy(v=vs.110).aspx) (a "generator function") which is useful for determining what do to dynamically.

> In a specified input string, replaces all strings that match a specified regular expression with a string returned by a MatchEvaluator delegate.

For example;

```
Regex.Replace(input, @"{(.*?)}", (m) => {
    // Use m (a Match object) and create the correct output
    return string.Format("<<Length:{0}>>", m.Groups[1].Value.Length);
});
```

Comment: Well that was easy! Thanks! its been a long day :P